# How to get the cropping coordinates of an image

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image

I am using CropImageView library instead of ImageView.And I need to get the cropping Coordinates of the imageView.
Is it possible?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Post any code or something....

Comment: I want to upload the actual image and cropped image coordinates to server.For this,I need the coordinates(or the starting position of the cropped image)

Comment: I want to upload the actual image and cropped image coordinates to server.For this,I need the coordinates(or the starting position of the cropped image) @Aspicas

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any good way?

Comment: I got the answer.Use cropImageView.getCropPoints() .It is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Use cropImageView.getCropPoints()

Comment: Provide some explanation with you answer as well.